# Service stops on clearing data from settings

Tags: android, android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver

in my app i run a **service** in which i keep record of incoming and out going calls on text file(saved it on internal storage) using **broadcastReciever**. but when i press clear data button(settings=>apps=>Myapp=>clear data) my service also stops. i used `Log.d()` in `onDestroy()` method but it is not logged in logcat when i press `clear data`.
i read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610775/service-stops-when-clearing-data) having same problem but i didn't find any solution. then i went through [Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). i am really confused.

Comment: Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092134/broadcast-receiver-within-a-service) that will help you to lead broadcast receiver on service of android

Comment: follow this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20465808/broadcastreceiver-doesnt-start-from-service?rq=1) this is the suitable answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The data associated the the app will no longer persist on clearing. To avoid this you need to sign your app as a system app.*

> Clear Data does kill the app, and always has.
>
> "Force Stop" has gone through various iterations of meanings. It used
>   to mean to just kill all processes and services, and clearing data
>   would also do the same as a force stop. There were also older
>   iterations of the platform that were not as good as figuring out when
>   to disable the button, which is probably why you are seeing it remain
>   enabled in 2.2.
>
> However in 3.2 I believe the meaning of "Force Stop" change to put the
>   application in a state where it would not be able to run until the
>   user had done something to explicitly start it (such as launching it
>   from launcher, selecting it as an input method, etc). When that change
>   was made, "Clear Data" continued to just kill the processes and stop
>   its services, so the app was not in the full stopped state so the
>   button remains enabled.

**Edit:**
Example of working code:

```
Step 1) Create one Android BroadCastReciever and register it for two action

Manifest

    <service android:name="ServiceTest" >
    </service>

    <receiver android:name="ReceiverCall" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.techtrainner" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
com.android.techtrainner is the custom action. BroadCastReceiver Class contain code to restart service again

public class ReceiverCall extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("Service Stops", "Ohhhhhhh");
        context.startService(new Intent(context, ServiceTest.class));;
    }

}
Step 2) Create Android service class , do some task there (I have taken one Timer to print Log) and in onDestory()

public void onDestroy() {
    try {
        mTimer.cancel();
        timerTask.cancel();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.techtrainner");
    intent.putExtra("yourvalue", "torestore");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Comment: i know the associated data no longer exists but why service stops?. my data (files and database) has nothing to do with my service.

Comment: then how do i restart it??

Comment: you need to start your application again, from there you can start your service

Comment: as this app is for monitoring app for employee, user will not be able to start it. so is there any way that  i can start service programatcally

Comment: Starting a service on boot with a Sticky flag is the normal way of doing this.

Comment: Kindly look at the below answer to start your service through broadcastReceiver, it may solve your issue. If it doesnt, come here again.